# Vue warning message

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

While compiling my vue2 project lot of warning message in my code any way to solve this quickly?

In visual studio code it takes lot of time to show this waning

Suggest me to how solve this using any extension or any formating tool?

```
warning: Replace `parseFloat(this.expectedcapitalgain·/·1000).toFixed(2)` with `⏎······································parseFloat(⏎········································this.expectedcapitalgain·/·1000⏎······································).toFixed(2)⏎····································` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1214:62:
  1212 |                                   <span class="graphtext">
  1213 |                                     <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i>
> 1214 |                                     Expected Capital Gain ({{parseFloat(this.expectedcapitalgain / 1000).toFixed(2)}})
       |                                                              ^
  1215 |                                   </span>
  1216 |                                   <br />
  1217 |                                   <span class="graphtext">


warning: Replace `parseFloat(this.ccashflow·/·1000).toFixed(2)` with `⏎······································parseFloat(this.ccashflow·/·1000).toFixed(⏎········································2⏎······································)⏎····································` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1219:61:
  1217 |                                   <span class="graphtext">
  1218 |                                     <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i>
> 1219 |                                     Cumulative Cash Flow ({{parseFloat(this.ccashflow / 1000).toFixed(2)}})
       |                                                             ^
  1220 |                                   </span>
  1221 |                                 </div>
  1222 |                               </div>


warning: Insert `⏎·······························` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1247:80:
  1245 |                             <div class="md-layout-item">
  1246 |                               <span class="graphtext">
> 1247 |                                 <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Net Cash Flow
       |                                                                                ^
  1248 |                                 <br />
  1249 |                               </span>
  1250 |                               <span class="graphtext">


warning: Insert `⏎·······························` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1251:73:
  1249 |                               </span>
  1250 |                               <span class="graphtext">
> 1251 |                                 <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Cumulative Net Cash Flow
       |                                                                         ^
  1252 |                               </span>
  1253 |                             </div>
  1254 |                           </div>


warning: Replace `Graph·Values·Are·In·Thousand·AED` with `⏎························Graph·Values·Are·In·Thousand·AED⏎······················` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1257:49:
  1255 |                         </template>
  1256 |                       </chart-card>
> 1257 |                       <h6 class="graphtext ral">Graph Values Are In Thousand AED</h6>
       |                                                 ^
  1258 |                     </div>
  1259 |                   </div>
  1260 |                 </template>


warning: Replace `·class="md-layout-item·md-size-100·md-medium-size-100·md-xsmall-size-100"` with `⏎··············class="md-layout-item·md-size-100·md-medium-size-100·md-xsmall-size-100"⏎············` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1268:17:
  1266 |         <template slot="tab-pane-3">
  1267 |           <div class="md-layout md-size-100">
> 1268 |             <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100 md-medium-size-100 md-xsmall-size-100">
       |                 ^
  1269 |               <global-sales-card header-color="green">
  1270 |                 <template slot="content">
  1271 |                   <div class="md-layout">


warning: Replace `·style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#3c4858;">Documents` with `⏎························style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#3c4858;"⏎······················>⏎························Documents⏎······················` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1273:26:
  1271 |                   <div class="md-layout">
  1272 |                     <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100 md-xsmall-size-100">
> 1273 |                       <h1 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#3c4858;">Documents</h1>
       |                          ^
  1274 |                       <table style="width:100%;">
  1275 |                         <tr>
  1276 |                           <td>


warning: Replace `Marin·Quays·-·Pro·forma·financials` with `⏎································Marin·Quays·-·Pro·forma·financials⏎······························` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1278:47:
  1276 |                           <td>
  1277 |                             <a href="#">
> 1278 |                               <li class="ahr">Marin Quays - Pro forma financials</li>
       |                                               ^
  1279 |                             </a>
  1280 |                           </td>
  1281 |                           <td>


warning: Replace `HiGuests·short·term·rental·report` with `⏎································HiGuests·short·term·rental·report⏎······························` (prettier/prettier) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1305:47:
  1303 |                           <td>
  1304 |                             <a href="#">
> 1305 |                               <li class="ahr">HiGuests short term rental report</li>
       |                                               ^
  1306 |                             </a>
  1307 |                           </td>
  1308 |                         </tr>


error: 'vueNumeralFilterInstaller' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1426:8:
  1424 | import VueEasyLightbox from "vue-easy-lightbox";
  1425 | Vue.use(VueEasyLightbox);
> 1426 | import vueNumeralFilterInstaller from "vue-numeral-filter";
       |        ^
  1427 | import { API_KEY } from "./Maps/API_KEY";
  1428 | import GoogleMapsLoader from "google-maps";
  1429 | GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = API_KEY;


error: 'APIService' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard2.vue:1439:10:
  1437 | import GoogleAtmMap from "../../components/GoogleAtmMap";
  1438 | import GoogleGymMap from "../../components/GoogleGymMap";
> 1439 | import { APIService } from "../../apiservice.js";
       |          ^
  1440 | import {
  1441 |   StatsCard,
  1442 |   ChartCard,


2 errors and 247 warnings found.
247 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080 
  - Network: http://192.168.0.105:8080
```

Like this it show the warning message every time compiling. any way to fix this intent waning using vscode

Comment: "247 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option." Try running `lint --fix`

Comment: bash: lint: command not found

Comment: Either install eslint globally or run `npm run lint --fix` as mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the error message, you can fix the problem by running the following command:

`$ npm run lint -- --fix`

In the future, you can get VSCode to automatically fix these problems by installing the ESLint extension, and enabling the `eslint.autoFixOnSave` option as documented here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint